# Migrate legacy v1 data to v2 database in Rails 6 app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I have a legacy database that I need to convert to a new database for a Rails 6 app. The legacy database has 21 columns and 900,000+ rows. I'm only interested in pulling certain column data with no duplicates based on the combination of two columns. I have columns called `depth`, `name`, `product_number` and `country`. I want to pull `name` and `product_number`, but only unique rows based on a combination of the `product_number` and the `country` where the `depth` is 1. For example, if I use product_number 11122000 and country AUS, I have 115 rows, but I only want one of those rows. I would like to have the result saved to a variable because I have to name the columns in the new database different than in the legacy database. I've written rake tasks for the other legacy database conversions, but I can't figure out how to pull these columns. I've tried this:

`Database.where(depth: 1).group(:product_number, country)`

This gives me a hash of arrays with the product_number and the country. How can I pull the name and product_number from this hash? Or is there a better way to pull the needed rows?

Comment: This sounds a bit more like a task that would be easier to solve by just using mysqldump instead of getting rails involved. Especially given the amount of data involved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in relational database theory, if you `group by` unique `product_number`, and `country` there can be multiple results and they could have different values for `name`.  So SQL doesn't know how to pick which row to use for the `name` value.

You might have to process this in ruby.

```
Database.where(depth: 1).group(:product_number, :country).map |db|
  Database.where(depth: 1, product_number: db.product_number, country: db.country).first
end
```